# How to exclude text in a gradient conditional format in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Fairly simple - I have a google sheet where I use the gradient formatting function to display the stats of game characters so that higher stats show bolder colors, etc. The problem is that in the same cells, we also include how much the stat has increased since last patch (so a single cell will contain "130 (+25)", for instance. However, including the (+25) portion breaks the conditional gradient formatting formula and makes it use the default color. Is there a way to write a program that reads the cells, trims the " (+25)" off, and feeds the "130" directly into the formatting rule? Or alternatively, is there a way to easily emulate the gradient formatting tool via program instead so it can directly trim its own inputs?

Comment: If you are expecting another answer below, kindly show your conditional format so I can adjust my answer to your needs.

Comment: NaziA thanks for the help - this is certainly useful information, however, I was hoping for a way to have the formatting applied to the original "130 (+25)" cell and to have it using the sheet's automatic color scale gradient formatting.

https://gyazo.com/88da298ca1234a30510a21a405012998
https://gyazo.com/2ddce17ee01dba93987b9e5aa9553858

With your way we can separate it into two columns per stat (which is our current solution but looks ugly) or we'd have to set up a long series of manual gradients using single color formatting. Is there a way to implement this function via scripts-

Comment: -to feed in the REGEXTRACT output into the gradient formatting, or a way to automatically imitate the effects of the color scale rule via scripts to get around this?

Comment: Hi @KATTech, I see. Can you provide a sample sheet that can show the actual data and another sheet to show its corresponding expected result? Also, kindly make sure the sheet is accessible to other people. Thanks

Comment: Hi @KATTech, I have modified my answer and provided an apps script approach since using formula or preprocessing the cells before the color scale format is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Apps Script solution for your issue. The solution below is based on a [JavaScript Interpolation Code](https://codepen.io/njmcode/pen/axoyD/).

#### Initial Sample Data:

[image: sample data]

Initially, only cells with pure numbers are being formatted and this leaves out the cells that are identified as texts due to other characters. This script below will manually set these cells with their own calculated background colors that are identical (if not the same) as tested using side by side comparison of the results from the script and the gradient formatting.

```
function customGradient() {
  // Logs all the information inside gradient conditional format rules on a sheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  for (i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
    var gradient = rules[i].getGradientCondition();
    // skip non gradient rules
    if (gradient) {
      // Assuming format is applied on a specific range
      var range = rules[i].getRanges()[0];
      var startRow = range.getRow();
      var startCol = range.getColumn();
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      // remove 1st value in range (assumed to be header)
      var values = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, lastRow - startRow + 1, 1).getValues().flat().filter(Boolean).slice(1);
      var outputColor = [];
      values.forEach(function (value) {
        var factor;
        var [minColor, midColor, maxColor] = [gradient.getMinColor(), gradient.getMidColor(), gradient.getMaxColor()];
        var [minValue, midValue, maxValue] = [gradient.getMinValue(), gradient.getMidValue(), gradient.getMaxValue()];
        // get only the left number
        value = value.toString().match(/^\d+/)[0];

        if(value <= midValue) {
          factor = (value - minValue) / (midValue - minValue);
          outputColor.push([r2h(interpolateColor(h2r(minColor),h2r(midColor), factor))]);
        }
        else {
          factor = (value - midValue) / (maxValue - midValue);
          outputColor.push([r2h(interpolateColor(h2r(midColor),h2r(maxColor), factor))]);
        }
      });
      // skip first row (assumed to be header)
      sheet.getRange(startRow + 1, startCol, lastRow - startRow, 1).setBackgrounds(outputColor);
    }
  }
}

// https://codepen.io/njmcode/pen/axoyD/
function h2r(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? [
        parseInt(result[1], 16),
        parseInt(result[2], 16),
        parseInt(result[3], 16)
    ] : null;
};

// Inverse of the above
function r2h(rgb) {
    return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (rgb[0] << 16) + (rgb[1] << 8) + rgb[2]).toString(16).slice(1);
};

// Get the intermediary color from two colors based on a factor
function interpolateColor(color1, color2, factor) {
  if (arguments.length < 3) { factor = 0.5; }
  var result = color1.slice();
  for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    result[i] = Math.round(result[i] + factor*(color2[i]-color1[i]));
  }
  return result;
};
```

#### Output:

- [image: output]

#### Note:

- The code above makes use of existing color scale conditional formats. It gets all the data of your rule and the script above iterates over them and manually store the calculated colors in an array and set them on their respective range by column.
- This should work on `onEdit` trigger but haven't tested. If it isn't a hassle to manually trigger the function to populate those cells, then the above code should work as is.
- If needed to be in an `onEdit` trigger, we need to improve the runtime by overhauling the said script. If you need it in a trigger, please say so.

#### Reference:

- [Conditional Format Rule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule)
- [JavaScript Interpolation](https://codepen.io/njmcode/pen/axoyD/)